# Table with blank spaces after nth cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I am trying to create a table that has 1 row and 8 columns. However, I want a blank spaces after the 3rd and 6th table cell. The result should be:

cell cell cell *blank space* cell cell cell *blank space* cell cell

I have tried placing margins but they don't work. I have tried implementing this code, but it doesn't work.

```
.brzl td:nth-child(3){
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**Edit:**

I am trying to implement this within an AngularJS project. In the index.html i have the following code:

```
<div ng-switch-when="brzl">
    <table class="brzl">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                 <td ng-repeat="cell in mini.vrednost track by $index">
                      {{ cell }}
                 </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <label class="small-label"> {{ mini.label }} </label>
</div>
```

The mini.vrednost basically loops through some JSON data (e.g. "123456789").
Each digit has to be placed within separate cell in the table. Now, once the '1','2', and '3' have been placed in the cells, I need to put an empty field after them and then continue with '4', '5' etc. The empty field cannot be read from the JSON data, since the whole string is already read from somewhere (I suppose the database).

I know I should have mentioned this earlier. That was my bad.

Comment: margin is not work with `table row` or `table cell`

Comment: you could change the width instead

Comment: consider uploading a fiddle, because the only option i see at the moment, is giving padding instead of margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Margin` doesn't work on table cells. However, `padding` does. Of course, if you have added borders to your table, this means you get one cell with a lot of white space.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2zwwobf/1/)

What you could do (through hard coding or by injecting with Javascript or jQuery) is add a blank cell where you want the white space, remove any styling of that cell through CSS and add a width.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2zwwobf/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell2</td>
            <td>cell3</td>
            <td></td> <!-- blank cell, no border -->
            <td>cell4</td>
            <td>cell5</td>
            <td>cell6</td>
            <td></td> <!-- blank cell, no border -->
            <td>cell7</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

td:nth-child(4n+4){
    border: none;
    width: 30px; /*desired blank space*/
}
```

As you can see, you'll have to target every 4th cell, starting with the 4th. If you have any questions, just ask and I'll see if I can adapt the answer accordingly.

**UPDATE AFTER OP'S EDIT**

However, since your table is filled with data by some script, you might want to run the following jQuery AFTER the loop is done filling up the table. I have no idea how it will react on huge tables with lots of content, but it works in the updated Fiddle below.

```
$('tr > td:nth-child(3n+3)').after('<td></td>');
```

This piece of jQuery takes every 3rd child, starting with the 3rd, and adds an empty `<td>` to it, which is then styled by the CSS. Of course you could ad a `<td>` with a specific class which you then target with CSS, but as it is now, it seems to work fine.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2zwwobf/2/)**

Remember to add jQuery!

Comment: Please check the Edit section. I have failed to mention some things. The solution that you suggested works fine for manually inserted tables.

Comment: Try to see if you can, instead of filling the `<td>` with `{{ cell }}`, also hide the `<td>` INSIDE the `{{ cell }}` variable. In this way, you can in theory create an empty `<td>` after every third time the `{{ cell }}` variable outputs something. Meanwhile, I'm going to see if I can find a jQuery solution for you.

Comment: @Superiom Well, that was easy! Let me know if it works!

Comment: If I hide the <td> within the {{ cell }} section, the value 'cell' is printed out.

Comment: Ok, so just continue as you were doing it (`<td> {{ cell }} </td>`) and add the small line of jQuery to insert a blank `<td>` after every third `<td>` that your `{{ cell }}` filled up.

Comment: Ok, I found a temporary solution that works fine. I will let you know once the proper solution is implemented.

Comment: You can't use my jQuery `<td>`-injection?

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't see your edit. I apologize. I will implement it later, tomorrow at latest. I thank your for your time and help.

Comment: I apologize for the late response. The jQuery code works like a charm. Thank you, kind sir.

Answer (score 0):

As i told you, you can't use margin but you can try like this method -

```css
table { 
    width: 100%;
}
td{
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
td:nth-child(3n){
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table width="50%">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
             <td>data</td>
             <td>data</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>data</td>
             <td>data</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>data</td>
             <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Or you can try this to set border on right side on `nth-child`

```css
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
td:nth-child(3n){
    border-right:10px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<table width="50%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
             <td>data</td>
             <td>data</td>
             <td>data</td>
             <td>data</td>
             <td>data</td>
             <td>data</td>
             <td>data</td>
             <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hf7abm4L/2/)**

```
td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding:10px;
}

td:nth-child(4n) {
   border-color: #fff;     
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td></td> <!-- 3,6,... cols should be empty to get blank space -->
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```